# Android 5.1 update stuck on "Waiting to download..."

Tags: updates, nexus-5, 5.1-lollipop

My Nexus 5 prompted me to update my Android to 5.1. When I clicked download, the process is stuck on "Waiting to download..." and there after nothing happened. I waited for almost 10 minutes, and then restarted my phone yet again it stuck on same phase "Waiting to download..."

**Edit:** It took more than 15 minutes to initiate the download. So please wait patiently :D

(I am leaving the question open so that other users can share their answer on what they did to overcome this issue.)

Comment: Faced the same issue , nothing special I did except waiting :)

Comment: Got the OTA update for Nexus 4 today, same issue. It took about 10 mins to initiate download.

Comment: I waited for a while. Then just plugged my phone into the wall, and it started immediately. Coincidence? Possibly.

Comment: My N5 didn't show the progress of the download, it showed waiting for download the whole time, then installed the rom correctly. So I would say to wait.

Answer (score 1):

It does take a long time to download. Make sure you are connected to wifi if possible and have your phone plugged in to your charger. I was able to schedule mine to happen overnight.